# RecyclerView only shown on minimized

Tags: java, php, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I use retrofit to get data from PHP(localhost) as JSON and display it with recycler view. My problem is my data never show whenever I go fullscreen(Image 1) and goes normal whenever I minimized the app(Image 2).

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znoUV.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RgH5.jpg)

Here is My Code:

Java/Kotlin

NetworkConfig

```
package com.example.simplemysqlproject

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import org.json.JSONObject
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.POST

class NetworkConfig {
    // set interceptor
    fun getInterceptor() : OkHttpClient {
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build()
        return  okHttpClient
    }
    fun getRetrofit() : Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.Root_URL)
                .client(getInterceptor())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }
    fun getService() = getRetrofit().create(Users::class.java)
}
interface Users {
    @POST("ShowUser.php/")
    fun getUsers(): Call<JsonObject>
}
```

UserTable

```
package com.example.simplemysqlproject

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.gson.JsonArray
import org.json.JSONException
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import org.json.JSONObject
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import java.util.*

class UserTable : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var rv: RecyclerView
    private var userAdapter:UserRVAdapter?=null
    private var userListData:MutableList<UserData> = ArrayList()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.read_user)
        initRecyclerView();
        showRetro();
        userAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    private fun showRetro(){
        var jsonObject:Callback<JsonObject>?=null
        NetworkConfig().getService()
                .getUsers()
                .enqueue(object :Callback<JsonObject>{
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObject>, response: Response<JsonObject>) {
                        var jsonArray=response.body()?.getAsJsonArray("data")
                        var b:Int=0
                        for(i in 0..(jsonArray?.size()?.minus(1)!!)){
                            userListData.add(UserData(jsonArray?.get(i)?.asJsonObject?.get("id")?.
                                asInt,jsonArray?.get(i)?.asJsonObject?.get("Username")?.asString,
                                    jsonArray?.get(i)?.asJsonObject?.get("email")?.asString))
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(this@UserTable, response.body()?.get("message").toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        userAdapter?.submitList(userListData)
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject>, t: Throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@UserTable, t.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                })
    }
    private fun addDataSet() {
        var stringRequest=StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.ShowAll_URL,
                com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                    try {
                        var jsonObject: org.json.JSONObject = org.json.JSONObject(response)
                        var jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")
                        for (a in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                            var b: org.json.JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a)
                            userListData.add(UserData(b.getInt("id"), b.getString("Username"), b.getString("email")))
                            userAdapter?.submitList(userListData)
                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                },
                com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener {

                }

        )


        var reqQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this@UserTable)
        reqQueue.add(stringRequest)
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        rv=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        rv.apply {
            layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this@UserTable)
            userAdapter=UserRVAdapter()
            adapter=userAdapter
        }
    }
}
```

UserData

```
package com.example.simplemysqlproject

data class UserData(

        var id: Int?,

        var username: String?,

        var email: String?


)
```

UserRVAdapter

```
package com.example.simplemysqlproject

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import java.util.*

class UserRVAdapter:RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){
    private val TAG: String = "AppDebug"

    private var items: List<UserData> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return BlogViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.user_data, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(holder) {

            is BlogViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(items.get(position))
            }

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    fun submitList(userList: List<UserData>){
        items = userList
    }

    class BlogViewHolder
    constructor(
            itemView: View
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val username:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername)
        val email:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail)

        fun bind(userdata: UserData){
            /*
            val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)

            */
            /*
            Glide.with(itemView.context)
                    .applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                    .load(blogPost.image)
                    .into(blog_image)
                    */
            username.setText(userdata.username)
            email.setText(userdata.email)
        }

    }

}
```

XML

read_user

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

user_data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/edit"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:tint="@color/purple_700" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/wrong"
                android:id="@+id/wrongButton"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
        </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

PHP
operationDB

```
<?php
    class OperationDB{
        private $con;
        function __construct(){
            require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/ConnectDB.php';
            $db= new ConnectDB();
            $this->con= $db->connect();
        }
        public function CreateUser($username,$password,$email){
            if($this->isUserExist($username,$email)){
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                $pass=md5($password);
                $CreateQuery=$this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `user data` 
                (`id`, `Username`,`Password`,`Email`) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?);");
                    $CreateQuery->bind_param("sss",$username,$pass,$email);
                if($CreateQuery->execute()){
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        }
        public function ShowAll(){
            $sql="SELECT id,Username,email FROM `user data`;";
            $result=mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
            return $result;
        }
        public function LoginUser($username,$password){
            $pass=md5($password);
            $LoginQuery=$this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM `user data` WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            $LoginQuery->bind_param("ss",$username, $pass);
            $LoginQuery->execute();
            $LoginQuery->store_result();
            return $LoginQuery->num_rows>0;
        }
        public function DeleteUser($id){
            $DeleteQuery=$this->con->prepare("DELETE from `user data` where id=?");
            $DeleteQuery->bind_param("i",$id);
        }
        private function isUserExist($username,$email){
            $CheckQuery=$this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM `user data` WHERE
            username=? or email=?");
            $CheckQuery->bind_param("ss",$username,$email);
            $CheckQuery->execute();
            $CheckQuery->store_result();
            return $CheckQuery->num_rows>0;
        }
    }
```

ShowUser

```
<?php
    require_once '../includes/OperationDB.php';
    $response=array();
    $dataArray=array();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $db=new OperationDB();
        if($OperationResult=$db->ShowAll()){
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($OperationResult)){
                $dataArray[]=$row;
            }
            $response['data']=$dataArray;
            $response['error']=false;
            $response['message']="Showing Data!";
        }
        else{
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']="Showing failed!";  
        }
    }
    else{
        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']="Invalid Request Bro";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because enqueue is asynchronously. You have to call notifyDataSetChanged after get data from callback

```
userAdapter?.submitList(userListData)
userAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

or

```
fun submitList(userList: List<UserData>){
        items = userList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```